# Drawing a semi-transparent window in wxwidgets

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, alphablending

I'm drawing an informational window using wx over a wxGLCanvas.  I want to have the ability to fade that window so it is alpha blended with the image rendered by OpenGL.  Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to not draw the background for the overlapping widget, but I only get a white rectangle.  I tried to use a wxGraphicsContext as well, with no success.

My next thought is to draw the window in a MemoryDC and composite the images in OpenGL, but that would prevent interaction from the user with anything in the window (at least through conventional means).  Any tips would be appreciated.  I'm using Windows 7 and wxPython.

Answer (score 1):

wx.Frames have a SetTransparent method that can accept a value from 0-255, with 0 being completely transparent and 255 being completely opaque. I'm not sure if that's what you're going for or not, but if it is, here's a tutorial on the subject: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/04/14/doing-a-fade-in-with-wxpython/

Comment: Thanks, but this only seems to work for top-level widgets.  What I want is for a child widget to be semi-transparent.  Maybe I could fake a child widget with a top-level frame, but that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Well, everything inside the frame will also be transparent. There is no way to select which ones will be transparent and which ones won't.